# What is the integral of $\ln(\ln(...(\ln(x))))$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have seen integral with $\ln(x)$ finute times on this site but in my book its $$ \int \ln(\ln(\underset{\text{n times}}{\cdots}(\ln(x))))$$ so what sort substitution should I do. $e^y$ or something like that.

Comment: For $n > 2$, there are no closed forms.

Comment: The partial integration is the way to go

Comment: How will you do for n times develop reccurence relation

Comment: Do you mean $\int \ln x \ln x \ln x\dots$ or $\ln(\ln(\ln(\dots)))$

Comment: Yes @ Nehorai.. Edited

Comment: @Henry W., is there a proof somewhere?

Comment: Option of edit closed i want to edit  that one can use recurrence